# Error when externalizing with TeXLive 2022

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, texlive, external

today I have decided to upgrade to TexLive 2022 from 2020. Just after the new version has been installed I have encounter the problem when running this simple file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,1) -- (10,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{cap}\label{some}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex -shell-escape test2.tex`. The console says:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interact
ion=batchmode -jobname "figures/test2-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test2}
\input{test2}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'figures/test2-figure0'
(expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled sy
stem calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is als
o named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed?
Error messages can be found in 'figures/test2-figure0.log'. If you continue now
, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.10   \end{tikzpicture}

?
! Emergency stop.
 ...

l.10   \end{tikzpicture}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test2.log.
```

There was no problem when using 2020 version. I appreciate any help with this.

BR, Piotr

Comment: Works for me...  Can you show the contents of `figures/test2-figure0.log`?

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! The problem is that `test2-figure0.log` does not exists. What I found is `test2-figure0.md5`. There is no other file under `figures/`.

Comment: That means that the pdflatex call didn't even start... What happens if you remove `prefix=figures`?  Also, write `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, then upload `test2.log` somewhere (e.g., pastebin)

Comment: When the `prefix=figures/` is removed the output is the same. The `.log` file is here: [test2.log](https://pastebin.com/eRGiQHDa).

Comment: The problem is that pdfTeX is not running with shell escape.  The third line in your log says `restricted \write18 enabled`, but it should be `\write18 enabled`, which means that the `-shell-escape` flag is not working (for whatever odd reason).  Since you're on Windows, try `--enable-write18` instead (no idea, I'm just guessing now)

Comment: you didn't enable -shell-escape.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `--shell-escape` should work (it does for me).

Comment: I have run it with `pdflatex --enable-write18 test2.tex` and it works! Thanks @PhelypeOleinik. Now, I have tried it with `--shell-escape` and it works too. Can't understand why one dash worked before (TL2020) and not now (TL2022) though. But that is not relevant.

Comment: @PiotrPtak Weird, both `--shell-escape` and `-shell-escape` should work (and do the same as `--enable-write18`, but it is preferrable to use `--shell-escape`).

Comment: Thanks again @PhelypeOleinik. It works now.